# AnyIterator and boost iterator facade

Tags: c++, iterator, any

Is it possible to implement an any iterator with boost iterator facade? 
I don't want to define implementation details in my baseclass

```
class Base
{
public:
typedef std::vector<int>::iterator iterator;//implementation detail
...
virtual iterator begin()=0;
virtual iterator end()=0;
};
```

or do i have to write one completely from scratch;

Comment: The way I would probably do it is to define an abstract base class like `Iterator<T>` that acts like a Java or C# iterator, a templated implementation of that for arbitrary iterators, then use Boost.Iterator to wrap an iterator interface on top of any `Iterator<T>`.  Do you want me to try to sketch out pseudocode for that?

Comment: You can find one at http://thbecker.net/free_software_utilities/type_erasure_for_cpp_iterators/any_iterator.html

Answer (score 9):

The code you've posted has fixed the type of iterators returned from `Base` and all it's implementantions to `std::vector<int>::iterator` which is probably not what you want. Jeremiah's suggestion is one way to go with one drawback: you loose compatibility with STL... I know of three implementations of a polymorphic iterator wrapper:

1. becker's `any_iterator` (which implements `boost::iterator_facade`)
2. the `opaque_iterator` library (google for it), or
3. Adobe's very interesting poly library which contains a hierarchy of STL conforming `any_iterator`s.

The problem is harder than it might seem... I made an attempt myself mainly because I needed covariance in `any_iterators` type argument (`any_iterator<Derived>` should be automatically convertible to `any_iterator<Base>`) which is difficult to implement cleanly with STL like iterators. A C# like `Enumerator<T>` is easier to implement(*) (and imho generally a cleaner concept than STL-like pairs of iterators) but again, you "loose" the STL.

(*) = without 'yield' of course :-)

Answer (score 3):

I think this may be what you're looking for:

> [any_iterator: Type Erasure for C++ Iterators](http://thbecker.net/free_software_utilities/type_erasure_for_cpp_iterators/any_iterator.html)

Here's a snippet from that page::

> **Overview**
>
> The class template any_iterator is the analog to boost::function for
>   iterators. It allows you to have a single variable and assign to it
>   iterators of different types, as long as these iterators have a
>   suitable commonality.